# JS: css property and value in one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties

```
var trns1 = '"transition": "all 1s"';
```

Why doesn't that work?

```
$('#box').css({"transform": "translate(xy)", trns1 });
```

Shouldn't that be exactly the same like:

```
$('#box').css({"transform": "translate(xy)", "transition": "all 1s" });
```

Comment: because this add a propertie called `trns1` with the value `transition ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Your JavaScript object isn't correct – you can't add a string in and expect it to work as a key value pair.

This will work:

```
var trns1 = { "transition": "all 1s"};
$('#box').css(trns1);
```

If you needed to add more options, you could do so easily:

```
var trns1 = { "transition": "all 1s"};
trans1.color = 'red';
trans1.height = '20px';
$('#box').css(trns1);
```

At the end of this `trans1` would be

```
{
    'color' : 'red',
    'height' : '20px',
    'transition': 'all 1s'
}
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment you can easily chain events in jQuery.

```
var trns1 = {"transition": "all 0.3s ease"};
var trns2 = {"transform": "translateY(4vw)"};
```

And then use them like this:

```
$('#box').css(trns1).css(trns2);
```

Comment: JSON is an object surely... that's what the O actually stands for?

Comment: great would be if i could do
var trns1 = {"transition": "all 0.3s ease"};
var trns2 = {"transform": "translateY(4vw)"};
and then use them like this: .css(trns1, trns2). i want to use them modular